# Anonymous types in C

Tags: c

I have the following recursive type definitions in C and I am wondering how to get it to work:

```
typedef int (*foo) (bar *);
typedef foo *bar;
```

The sizes of the pointers are well known so this should be OK.

I somehow need to forward declare bar as some anonymous type that I can then typedef correctly. Not sure how to do this in C since it isn't a struct

I want to avoid declaring foo as:

```
typedef int (*foo) (void *)
```

because then I lose some type checking properties.

Comment: Isn't it what `void*` is for in C?

Comment: Different pointers are allowed to have different sizes. In particular, function pointers are allowed to be incompatible with data pointers, including `void*`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no forward declaration for `typedef`s in C, unfortunately.

### UPD.

You can create indirectly recursive type as follows:

```
struct bar;
typedef int (*foo)(struct bar *);

struct bar {
    foo f;
};
```

And then get pointer to function through the field of the argument. But this requires the structure to be allocated somewhere (may be on stack) and additional pointer dereferencing.

```
int boo(struct bar *bar) {
    return (bar->f)(bar); // infinite loop
}

int main(void) {
    struct bar baz = { &boo };
    return boo(&baz);
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the second aliases `bar` to be a pointer to `foo`.

Comment: I'm amazed that c doesn't have this.